# custom image format to store multiple images (layers) in action script 3 approaches

Tags: actionscript-3, arrays

what is best method to store multiple images (layers) , so user can read(load) again and continue work.

1. currently doing this - each layer is stored as png file. with one text file
   contain all layers name etc
2. create one big png file, put all data in it as tiles. read tiles while loading..
3. create some custom format.

ideally, i wanted to implement c. but i need some guidance about where to start from.
my mind always tells me that, logically it should be simple as..

psudo code

layer 1 name, layer1 resolution

layer 1 png data (using png encoder for my bitmapData)

layer 2 name, layer2 resolution

layer 2 png data (using png ecncoder for my bitmapData) etc.

and so on....

but i never ever find a good starting point. this byte array always confuses me.
any one can guide me towards some steps about how to start. or
some logical flash / flex sample doing same would be of great help.
thanks for your time reading and huge thanks again for helping me. great community here..

Comment: Are you trying to code flash in flash ? I might not understand fully what you are trying to achieve.. But you could use loaders and stack them in a sprite ? Just add them to the display when they are loaded. And use a XML file to store names & file path ?

Comment: yes, but its air app. i want user to save data on disk/ quit app. reopen his project and continue.
its not flash in flash. because its pixels (not vectors) user painting application..(small) for some specific purpose

Comment: even about vectors, i always wanted to save my sprite (layers as childs) as swf on disk. load it agian similarly with structure.. but i heard, if its not impossible, its really hard to implement..not sure, though..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are afraid of byteArray, you can do your first solution but storing all files into a Zip file. It will be nice because you can view Zip simply and all files are packaged into one file.

There is several library in As3 for Zip format :

- http://nochump.com/blog/archives/15
- http://codeazur.com.br/lab/fzip/

Comment: thanks, can u please share some resources to reduce my fear about byte array as well. btw, thanks for zip libs, for sure, it will help to produce towards decent solution

Comment: You should read Thibault Imbert book's avaible here : http://www.bytearray.org/?p=711 (chatper 2)